# Plasma5: Access Denied, Cannot Write On /home/

Tags: permissions, kde, plasma-5

I run Plasma 5 on Ubuntu 18, and when i try to edit some settings on System Preferences like adding apps on system start or installing a theme,it doesnt work. 
A warning message appears saying: "Access Denied, cannot write on /home/my_user/.config/autostart/app_name.desktop"

Its something about permissions for sure,i dont know how to fix it and I dont think running System Preferences as root its a good solution.

The output of `ls -ld ~/.config/autostart` is:
 rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 abr 16 01:50 /home/user_name/.config/autostart
and command `ls -l ~/.config/autostart/app_name.desktop` says that the file doesn't exit (i cannot copy manually in this directory unless i'm root).

Comment: what does this `ls -ld ~/.config/autostart` command return and how about `ls -l ~/.config/autostart/app_name.desktop`? Please edit your question to include this information.

Answer (score 3):

Owner of files and folders in `~/.config` should be user, not `root`.

To fix, run this:

```
sudo chown -R $USER: ~/.config
```

Comment: Just fixed. I didn't know what type of permissions this folder needed.